# AngularJS : UI Bootstrap Tabs and Jquery Custom ScrollBar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my view, I have 2 tabs generated by the UI-Bootstrap Tabs directive.

The tabs have fixed heights and "overflow-y: auto;", and receive variable content.

I'm trying to apply some nice scroolbars using the Jquery plugin **[Custom Content Scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)**,
through a custom directive.

The custom directive is fired within the tabs.

The Custom Content Scroller Plugin comes with callbacks, which I need to make some absolute positioned gradients to visually blend the upper and lower borders of the scrollable area to the background color.

**VIEW**

```
<tabset> // UI BOOTSTRAP DIRECTIVE
    <tab 
    ng-repeat="tab in tabs" // 2 TABS
    heading="{{ tab.title | translate}}" 
    id="tab{{tab.id}}" 
    active="tab.active" 
    disabled="tab.disabled" >

        <div class="col-sm-9 TabContent_container">

            <div class="TabContent" customscrollbar ng-attr-tabnumber="{{tab.id}}">
                <div marked="tab.TabContent | translate"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="gradient_top" id="gradient_top_{{tab.id}}"></div>
            <div class="gradient_bottom" id="gradient_bottom_{{tab.id}}"></div>

        </div>

    </tab>
</tabset>
```

**APP.JS**

```
app.directive('customscrollbar', function() {

    return {
        scope: {},

        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {

        tabnumber = attrs.tabnumber;
        console.log(tabnumber); // AS EXPECTED : 1, THEN 2 (DUE TO tab ng-repeat)


        elem.mCustomScrollbar({ // SEEMS TO PROPERLY GENERATE AN INSTANCE FOR EACH TAB
            theme:"dark", 

            callbacks:{
                onScrollStart: function(){
                alert('tabnumber : '+tabnumber); // ALWAYS RETURNS 2 !
                }
            }
        });

        } // ----- EOF - link: function
    }; // ----- EOF - return
});
```

Why is the ***onScrollStart*** callback referring to tab 2, while in the UI the scrollers generated are independent? The content on tab 1 scrolls independently from tab 2, but the callback is fired for both tabs, and always returns the second tab?

I also found this strange while testing :

```
    app.directive('customscrollbar', function($timeout) {

    return {
        scope: {},

        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {

        element_width = elem[0].offsetWidth; // FIRST PASS (TAB 1), RETURNS CORRECT WIDTH
                                             // SECOND PASS (TAB 2), RETURNS 0 !

        } // ----- EOF - link: function
    }; // ----- EOF - return
});
```

What in the Angular world is happening?

Comment: I have had various issues with the UI-Bootstrap tabset, I usually end up just using the proper twitter bootstrap one and doing what I need to with that, might be easier in the long run

Answer (score 0):

You have declared ***"tabnumber"*** as global variable that's why it couldn't be able to support closure . define it as local ***var tabnumber = attrs.tabnumber;*** it would work fine.

Comment: Damn, I always get confused. "var foo = bar;" means local, and "foo = bar;" global? I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: I have some emergencies at the moment, I'll give it a try ASAP and will get back to you.

Comment: yes .. and try to avoid make variable global .. does my answer correct ?